# Database for US towns and cities needed

Tags: csv

I have spent hours and hours looking for a database, CSV, Excel, list containing certain states, towns/cities, country, and Lat / Long data at a minimum. I've seen a few but they only had cities. Building an IDX app and want to look up municipalities within X miles of a chosen one. I have one, that I got long ago, but it does not have all towns. Unincorporated towns would be needed.

Can anyone help here? There must be something.
BTW, Looking for VT, NH, ME, and MA

thanks in advance

Comment: question doesnt really belong to SO, I guess, but maybe look into the [OSMNames](https://osmnames.org/) dataset

Comment: repro steps are *always* helpful.  in this case, saying what ones you saw that weren't good enough and specific towns you expected that weren't there.  (but this question isn't a good fit for stackoverflow)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend an offline resource are explicitly off topic here on SO

Comment: Kaggle is a good way to start if you look for "dataset of X".

Answer (score 0):

OK, for those of you in the same situation, after many hours of digging, downloading, etc. I found Geonames Org, very extensive list. Had to do a bit of work to get what I needed as the list contained just about everything, towns, counties, laces, things, and more.

I am also exploring US Cities Org. They may contain not only what I need, but, extra demographic data which may be useful.

Take care